# Issue with deleting lengthy filename under node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin

Tags: node.js, batch-file, webpack

Can someone help with the following issue.

I have a .bat script to delete the existing dir before i clone the repo.

`rmdir /s /q "some_directory"`

the console has this problem -

`node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\b2\8c\10f540505bd019bf69a5851682a239aa929ce29bb3b831040dcb28e081885df25d88f1da917067e51437593d03562f5079b76d5d6550e801083a5c69bc5f` - The system cannot find the path specified.

How to delete this .cache folder with the lengthy file name and move forward.

I am not directly using terser-webpack-plugin in my `package.json` but `package-lock.json` has a dependency.

Please help.

Comment: Please change the title to be clearer and more concise.

Comment: I changed let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sure, I'm just a moderator and have no idea about your issue!

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on other developer's machine and QA's machine. They don't have any issue.It is something to do with my machine.

Comment: Hi Aleaplis, this may be better as an edit to your original question, or a comment, as opposed to an answer.